# Configuring postfix or other software to route mail through Cloudflare or other ddos protection?

Tags: postfix, ddos, cloudflare

So I'm looking to set up my own mail server with postfix, but I've currently routed my web server through CloudFlare. Is there a way to route all outbound emails through some sort of proxy or ddos protection, so my server's IP address is not exposed?

I know very little about ddos protection on anything other than websites. Does it make more sense for me to rent an additional server to have a different IP address than my web server?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is your concern? With modern spam filtering there is zero chance you are going to be able to send email reliably if you try to mask your server IP address. It is a necessity that that information is not only available but that the server properly identify itself to any server it expects to send mail to.

Comment: I don't want to jeopardize the stability and uptime of my webserver but adding postfix to it. If doing this exposes my IP address, then it will be much easier for potential attackers to ddos the server. So would it make the most sense to rent a separate server for mail to avoid exposing the IP address of my webserver?

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: hosted email is generally a good investment if you value your time.

Hosting your own server is really only useful if you want to learn about setting up and maintaining email servers, if you have some non-standard requirement such as encryption, or if your number of users makes a hosted email service expensive. You'll probably spend a fair bit of time administering or maintaining the if you have many users.

I don't know any easy way to route email through a proxy. There may be an email proxy service out there that can do spam filtering, but it's not commonly used.

Running your own email server you point your MX records at the server. If you have the server behind CloudFlare so your public IP isn't generally available then the MX record will tell people your actual server IP. All IPs on the internet are regularly scanned or attacked, but if your service is controversial then making your IP address public may increase this.

Comment: So I am working on a project which requires me to basically create a customized web-based email interface (think support ticket system that handles incoming and outgoing emails). I also would like to have full control over my email accounts for both my company and my clients. Nothing I host is controversial, but I'm bringing bigger clients on board and I want to be as responsible as I can be to thwart potential attackers from easily ddosing any of our servers. Any recommendations?

Comment: I still think you'd be best outsourcing email to a service who specializes in email, so long as it can support what you need. Generally the email+casenumber@example.com format (+ and later) can help use one email box. It really depends on the details though. I spent three months learning to set up Linux systems from scratch, compiling software, optimizing my websites, but I decided to stick with hosted email as it was too much effort to do email, particularly spam filtering. Commercial spam filters are great, open source only ok IMHO. Google / MS / Fastmail.